# Class is not added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add dark overlay to images by adding class `imgoverlay` using `jQuery`.

```js
$("#featured .row .col-sm img").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('imgoverlay');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('imgoverlay');
  }
);
```

```css
.imgoverlay {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(18, 15, 65, 0.7);
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main" id="featured" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-end" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div>
        <span class="sub-title"><p align="right" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="3000"> مشاريع مميزة </p></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <p align="right"><strong>  مشاريعنا الأخرى<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></strong></p>
        </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Gallery start -->
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1"><img name="Auoya" src="assets/images/thumb1resize.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1"><img name="capitalHeights" src="assets/images/thumb2resize.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb2"><img name="hai-sakani" src="assets/images/thumbMiddleresize.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1"><img name="bosco" src="assets/images/thumb3resize.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1"><img name="armonia" src="assets/images/thumb4resize.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a css:hover instead of jQuery? Pseudo element will get you what you need at half the price :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 1):

## Pure CSS

You can use `pseudo element` `::after` or `::before`, no need to use `JS` or `jQ` just add a global `class` and set `hover` effect on `::after` and active it on `:hover`

```css
.thumbs:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(18, 15, 65, 0.7);
}

.thumbs {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="main" id="featured" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-end" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div>
        <span class="sub-title"><p align="right" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="3000"> مشاريع مميزة </p></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <p align="right"><strong>  مشاريعنا الأخرى<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></strong></p>
        </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Gallery start -->
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1 thumbs"><img name="Auoya" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoQEfG25HrwwvXqpLkQfVMQk3PxQ7Q8CEH8oZx9MGfG04JlnLd" alt=""></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1 thumbs"><img name="capitalHeights" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoQEfG25HrwwvXqpLkQfVMQk3PxQ7Q8CEH8oZx9MGfG04JlnLd" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb2 thumbs"><img name="hai-sakani" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoQEfG25HrwwvXqpLkQfVMQk3PxQ7Q8CEH8oZx9MGfG04JlnLd" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1 thumbs"><img name="bosco" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoQEfG25HrwwvXqpLkQfVMQk3PxQ7Q8CEH8oZx9MGfG04JlnLd" alt=""></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="thumb1 thumbs"><img name="armonia" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRoQEfG25HrwwvXqpLkQfVMQk3PxQ7Q8CEH8oZx9MGfG04JlnLd" alt=""></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```